# error: cannot increment value of type 'char [6]'

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, string-literals

I am trying to learn pointers and string literals in C/C++.
As per my understanding, string literals are char arrays with a null `\0` at the end. Also we can basically do all the pointer arithmetic operations on array like increment and decrement.

But when I am trying to run the following code:

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

int main (){
    char *c ="Hello";
    char d[6];

    while(*d++ = *c++);

    cout<<c<<endl<<d;
}
```

I am getting the following error,

```
error: cannot increment value of type 'char [6]'
    while(*d++ = *c++);
```

My assumption for this code was, that the values of `string literal c` will be copied to `char array d`.

**Edit:**
Now I am a bit confused about the difference between these 2 statements:

```
*(d++)
```

and

```
*(d+1)
```

assuming `d` is an array.

Comment: As your compiler told you, you can't do pointer arithmetic on arrays (the reason being that arrays are not pointers). If your book told you that you can, you need a new book.

Comment: "Also we can basically do all the pointer arithmetic operations on array like increment and decrement."  No.

Comment: Note that in C++, we'd usually write `std::string c = "Hello"; std::string d = c;`.

Comment: @harshs08 - if you are in the process of learning programming, it could be a good idea to avoid stuff like `while(*d++ = *c++);` Too many things happens in this line. Consequently it can be difficult to understand what goes wrong. Use simple statements so that you only do one thing per line. Example: One line with `*d = *c;` Another line with `d++;` Another with `c++;`. When you get a compile error, it will be much easier to know what the compiler is complaining about.

Comment: @molbdnilo, @Lundin This was my assumption based on the understanding of whatever I read. Now after you have seeing your comments and the answers I understood what stupid thing I was doing. I think my whole confusion came from not understanding the clear difference between, `*(d++)` and `*(d+1) `  assuming that d is an char array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
char d[6];
while(*d++ = *c++);
```

Should be Re-written to:

```
char d[6];
int idx = 0;
while(d[idx++] = *c++);
```

Because in `char d[6];`, `d` is an array (not to be confused with pointer) and you can not change the address of an array. On the other hand, type of `c` is `char *` so you can modify it.

```
c++; // OK
c = &d[0]; // OK

d++; // Not allowed
d = c; // Not allowed
```

---

About your added question:

> Difference between: *(d++) and *(d+1)

Consider following example:

```
int index1 = 42, index2 = 42;
int j = index1++; // j = 42 and index1 = 43
int k = (index2 + 1); // k = 43 and index2 = 42 (unchanged)
```

Similarly when you write `*(d++)`, you are trying to access (by dereferencing) the current location and then increment the pointer itself to next location. But when you write `*(d + 1)`, you are accessing the next location and the pointer itself remains **unchanged**.

If the `d` pointer is constant or is an array first form (where d is changed) is not allowed but the second form (where the pointer itself remains unchanged) is allowed.

Comment: Or `char* pd = &d[0]; while (*pd++ = *c++);` - you can use two pointers.

Comment: @Mohit, Thanks alot. Now I understood the difference between arrays and pointers a bit. Need to see more examples and practice to wrap my head around this.

Answer (score 1):

> Array name can't be a modifiable lvalue

so

```
d++
```

can be written as

```
d = d+1;
```

So there is an error which should be fixed as

```
while(d[index++] = *c++);
```